# How to use Intel MKL / IPP in a real time audio program?

Tags: c++, signal-processing, intel-mkl, intel-ipp

I'm trying to use Intel's libraries to compute an FFT in real time for an audio application. I've tried both MKL and IPP and I can't get either of them to work. They both just completely freeze my DAW or crash it. I thought it might have something to do with calling all the initialisations over and over in the function thats doing the implementation (which needs to be repeated continuously), but I have to do this because I can only access the library's functions and whatnot from inside of a function, and I if I set everything up in a separate function I can't access it from the implementation function.
Anyone have any experience with these libraries? Are they suitable for real-time applications?
Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi, you should add more details about the application you are writing for. A minimal sample code that shows what you are trying to achieve or even better a minimal project that people can build/run to help you.

Comment: Are you writing a plug-in? You can probably move the initialisation elsewhere.